# How to subtract two dataframe on the value of one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

have two dataframe in of same schema and i am trying to get the different rows from both the dataframes based on the value of one column. i want to compare on id column and then get all the rows where the id and key is same but not present in both

dataframe1

```
Key id group
100 1  100_1
101 1  101_1
102 1  102_1
100 2  100_2
101 2  101_1
102 2  102_1
```

dataframe2:

```
Key id group
100 1 100_1
101 1 101_1
103 1 103_1
100 2 100_2
101 3 101_3
```

The result should look like this

```
Key id group Flag
102 1 102_1   1
103 1 103_1   0
101 2 101_2   1
102 2 102_2   0
101 3 101_3   0
```

I've tried to get difference between both

```
df_diff=pd.concat(df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

but it simply giving me the different rows between both also i tried outer join but it also didn't gives expected result.

```
join = df1.merge(df2.drop_duplicates(),on=['id','key','group'],how='left',indicator=True)
```

also

```
df1.subtract(df2).show()
```

but i can't figure out that how to get those rows from df1 with same id but diff key and group.

Comment: please don't repost your question, if you don't have the answer you want it's because the question is unclear, you must provide a better logic.

Comment: For instance, why do you keep `102/1/102_1` but drop `100/2/100_2`? This doesn't make sense.

Comment: the logic if the id is same in both the df then compare the key and the group and the output should be all those rows which are not  same in both df

Comment: Then my answer in your original (now-deleted) question should have worked